# Set lists bulletpoint's style

Tags: vba, list, ms-word

I am setting some text as a list, and it displays with thick black dots. I am strugling to set the lists starting with "-" instead of dots.

Setting the list:

```
oDoc.Paragraphs.Add() '17
iStartIndex = oDoc.Paragraphs.Count
oDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text = strUmfang
iEndIndex = oDoc.Paragraphs.Count

oDoc.Range( Start := oDoc.Paragraphs(iStartIndex).Range.Start, End := 
oDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.End ).Select()

Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault
```

I tried to set with:

```
ListGalleries.Item(3).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1).NumberFormat = ChrW(61485)
```

It keeps displaying as black dots.

Comment: record a macro while doing it manually and you should get the syntax needed

Comment: Already recorded a macro and the provided code didn't allow me to change styles :(

Comment: Did any of the suggestions posted as an Answer help? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to record a macro that set up a new list style using the dash character. To create my test, I set up a blank document with 5 paragraphs of text:

[image]

Then, from the recorded macro, I created a separate `Sub` to initialize my new `ListTemplate` for a list style that uses a dash:

```
Private Function CreateCustomListStyle(ByRef oDoc As Document) As ListTemplate
    With ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
        .NumberFormat = ChrW(8210)
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleBullet
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 0
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = "Calibri"
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1).Name = ""
    Set CreateCustomListStyle = ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1)
End Function
```

And finally, my test code to select all the paragraphs and make the list:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim oDoc As Document
    Set oDoc = ThisDocument

    oDoc.Range.Select       'selects all paragraphs
    Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault

    '--- create a list template that uses "-"
    Dim dashTemplate As ListTemplate
    Set dashTemplate = CreateCustomListStyle(oDoc)

    Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
        dashTemplate
End Sub
```

With the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you got the `ListGalleries.Item(3).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1).NumberFormat = ChrW(61485)` as a result from your recording, you probably changed the style definition, but never applied it.

If you do the same recording again and examine it, you will hopefully find that it associated that to a style. A line that looks something like `.LinkedStyle = "List Paragraph"`, but perhaps in German.

Work that part in to your existing macro and then, after selecting relevant parts of your document, do a

```
Selection.Style = ListGalleries.Item(3).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1).LinkedStyle
```

Comment: thanks! I didnt attach the created style to the selection